# How can i get all the MAX values from a certain column in a dataset in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, max

I'm asked to find the top user for different countries, however, one of the countries has 2 users with the same amount spent so they should both be the top users, but I can't get the max value for 2 values in this country.
Here is the code:

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT c.customerid,SUM(i.total) tot
FROM invoice i
JOIN customer c ON c.customerid = i.customerid
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
),
t2 AS (
SELECT c.customerid as CustomerId   ,c.firstname as FirstName,c.lastname as LastName, i.billingcountry as Country,MAX(t1.tot) as TotalSpent
FROM t1
JOIN customer c
ON c.customerid = t1.customerid
JOIN invoice i ON i.customerid = c.customerid
GROUP BY 4
ORDER BY 4
)
SELECT *
FROM t2
```

BILLINGCOUNTRY is in Invoice, and it has the name of all the countries.

TOTAL is also in invoice and it shows how much is spent for each purchase by Customer (so there are different fees and taxes for each purchase and total shows the final price payed by the user at each time)

Customer has id,name,last name and from its' ID I'm extracting the total of each of his purchases

MAX was used after finding the sum for each Customer and it was GROUPED BY country so that i could find the max for each country, however I can't seem to find the max of the last country that had 2 max values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`:

```
SELECT c.*, i.tot
FROM (SELECT i.customerid, i.billingCountry, SUM(i.total) as tot,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.billingCountry ORDER BY SUM(i.total) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM invoice i
      GROUP BY 1, 2
     ) i JOIN
     customer c
     ON c.customerid = i.customerid
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

The subquery finds the amount per customer in each country -- and importantly calculates a ranking for the combination with ties having the same rank.  The outer query just brings in the additional customer information that you seem to want.

Comment: it keeps giving an error:
Test failed:
near "(": syntax error\

Comment: from what i checked this is a really good idea, but maybe it is not working because the system doesn't allow us to use methods other than what we learned.
tried using UNION before to see if it would work if i added the last record manually and it still didn't work so it seems i am forced to use stuff like 
RANK,WITH,HAVING,JOIN,GROUP BY....etc

Comment: Could you please paste you entire query and which line it is giving error.

Comment: @Testuser1 . . . The syntax is fine (once I added the missing table alias):  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9e239064d725410eb55e6d58bf63c9ff.

Comment: that is the problem, it doesn't give me which line the error was, and i copied the same code you had, it didn't work too so it seems as i told you, the issue is with the system not allowing us to use different commands that we didn't take.
```
SELECT c.*, i.tot
FROM (SELECT i.customerid, i.billingCountry, SUM(i.total) as tot,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.billingCountry ORDER BY SUM(i.total) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM invoice i
      GROUP BY 1, 2
     ) i JOIN
     customer c
     ON c.customerid = i.customerid
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```
Test failed:
near "(": syntax error

Comment: it seems the issue is as i told you, because when i tried to use RIGHT JOIN it said it was not supported.
However it eventually worked thanks for  the hellp

Answer (score 0):

here is how it worked for me since i was restricted from using many Commands such `RIGHT JOIN` and `RANK()` (As what Gordon Linoff suggessted) so i had to create a 3rd case for the anamoly and join it using union. this solution works only on this case, the good solution is the one posted by Gordon Linoff:

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT c.customerid,SUM(i.total) tot
FROM invoice i
JOIN customer c ON c.customerid = i.customerid
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
),
t2 AS (
SELECT c.customerid as CustomerId   ,c.firstname as FirstName,c.lastname as LastName, i.billingcountry as Country,MAX(t1.tot) as TotalSpent 
FROM t1
JOIN customer c
ON c.customerid = t1.customerid
JOIN invoice i ON i.customerid = c.customerid
GROUP BY 4
ORDER BY 4
) ,
t3 AS (
SELECT DISTINCT c.customerid as CustomerId  ,c.firstname as FirstName,c.lastname as LastName, i.billingcountry as Country,t1.tot as TotalSpent  
FROM t1
JOIN customer c
ON c.customerid = t1.customerid
JOIN invoice i ON i.customerid = c.customerid
WHERE i.billingcountry = 'United Kingdom'
ORDER BY t1.tot DESC
LIMIT 2
)
SELECT *
FROM t2
UNION 
SELECT * FROM t3
ORDER BY t2.country
```